# Implementing a Video via iframe, vimeo or self hosted?

Tags: html, css, iframe, video, vimeo

This is my first time implementing a video within a website. I have uploaded the website to vimeo and was going to use that as my host, however I DO have the video on my server also. There are a few things about the vimeo hosting that I do not like. eg. the buttons and the outro of recommendations that they include, but I absolutely love how their code positions the video on the page, full width etc.

Below is the code I took from the vimeo developers page and it works great. This may be a really stupid question but could somebody show me how to adapt the code for a self-hosted video.

```
 <li>
            <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/114867351?api=1;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=d01e2f&amp;autoplay=1" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</li>
```

Within your answer could you also advise as to whether you would host your own video or use a website like Vimeo to host, as I am not sure what to do for the best.

This will be removed when the question is answered but here is a [livelink](http://www.cambridgedesigncompany.com/index2.html) to page with the video included.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 can support videos directly.

```
<video controls autoplay style="whatever css styles you fancy go here.">
  <source src="yourvideo.mp4" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML 5.
</video>
```

That's pretty much it. It will not however work with older browsers.

I wouldn't do this, because it will use up your bandwidth and put unnecssary stress on your server. Otherwise, fine. E.g. if you have a high-end dedicated server and you're not expecting to get a surge of users at any one point in time, then it should be fine. Otherwise, you're better off hosting externally.

Another benefit of hosting on Vimeo is that it does all the donkey-work for you in terms of getting a responsive video container and making sure it works with the maximum number of devices possible.

There is no wrong way of doing it - It just depends on what you're trying to achieve, what your server is capable of, and what your users are like.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think I shall stick with vimeo then however is there any way other than paying to get out of having the outro? Maybe a loop? Or can I disable the video near the end?

Comment: You can loop vimeo videos. [Click here](https://vimeo.com/help/faq/sharing-videos/embedding-videos#how-do-i-set-videos-to-autoplay-or-loop-when-i-embed-them) - however, removing the outro completely requires a paid account.